# Why is Elif printning after some list inputs?

Tags: python, if-statement

So im coding a shopping basket and its printing the elif statement after some of the items have been entered like "ham". Why?

Ive already tried adding the while loop into the items list but this hasnt worked.

```
print("What would you like? We have:")
## A function to call anywhere throughout the code to be able to print 
the item list
def item_List():
    print(" - Milk")
    print(" - Bread")
    print(" - Butter")
    print(" - Salt")
    print(" - Pepper")
    print(" - Ham")
    print(" - Steak")
    print(" - Banana Bunch")
    print(" - Apple Tray")
    print(" - Grapes")
    print(" - Winegums")
    print(" - Black Jacks")
    print(" - Sugar")
    print(" - Honey")
    print(" - Tea Bags")
    print(" - Coffee")

()
## Function caller
item_List()


## Variable set to a list for future appends
items = []

total = 0
addmore = True
while addmore == True:
    print("Add an item or type stop.")
    userInput = input()
    if userInput.lower() == "stop":
        addmore = False
    else:
        if userInput.lower() == "milk":
            total += 1.55
        if userInput.lower() == "bread":
            total += 1.82
        if userInput.lower() == "butter":
            total += 1.29
        if userInput.lower() == "salt":
            total += 1.20
        if userInput.lower() == "pepper":
            total += 1.20
        if userInput.lower() == "ham":
            total += 1.99
        if userInput.lower() == "steak":
            total += 3.99
        if userInput.lower() == "banana bunch":
            total += 2.25
        if userInput.lower() == "apple tray":
            total += 1.52
        if userInput.lower() == "grapes":
            total += 1.41
        if userInput.lower() == "winegums":
            total += 0.85
        if userInput.lower() == "black jacks":
            total += 0.85
        if userInput.lower() == "sugar":
            total += 2.95
        if userInput.lower() == "honey":
            total += 0.85
        if userInput.lower() == "tea":
            total += 2.85
        if userInput.lower() == "coffee":
            total += 3.05
        elif userInput not in items:
            print("Please enter a valid item.")

## List append for user to change their shopping basket by adding items 
to their basket
    items.append(userInput)
    print("Item added. Basket Total:","£",round(total,3))

## This prints the of their basket/list
print("\n--- Your Shopping List ---")
for i in items:
    print(i.title())

## This prints the total of their basket/list
print("Total: £"+str(total))
```

the output shouldnt show "please enter a valid item", it should just add that item and ask for another input.

Comment: `elif` only applied to your *last* `if` clause

Comment: `items` is your shopping list, not the list of available items. The logic is incorrect.

Comment: Your conditional says "if the item isn't coffee, and it is not already in your shopping basket, it's an invalid item".

Answer (score 4):

The `elif` is relevant only to the last `if` before it. You would want to change all `if`s to `elif` (except of the first of course).

Personally I like to implement this switch format using a dictionary. I would create a dictionary containing all available items with their prices.

```
items = {"milk": 1.55, "bread": 1.82, "butter": 1.29, "salt": 1.2, "pepper": 1.2, "ham": 1.99, "steak": 3.99, "banana bunch": 2.25, "apple tray": 1.52, "grapes": 1.41, "winegums": 0.85}
```

now the `item_List` function can be shorter:

```py
    def item_List(items):
        for item in items:
            print("- {}".format(item.title()))
```

and the else part of the while loop can be:

```py
    try:
        cost = items[uerInput.lower()]
        total += cost
    except KeyError:
        print("Please enter a valid item.")
```

Your whole code simplified:

```py
    items = {"milk": 1.55, "bread": 1.82, "butter": 1.29, "salt": 1.2} # etc...

    print("What would you like? We have:")

    for item in items:
        print("- {}".format(item.title()))

    shopping_list = []
    total = 0
    while:
        print("Add an item or type stop.")
        userInput = input()
        if userInput.lower() == "stop":
            break

        try:
            cost = items[uerInput.lower()]
            total += cost
            shopping_list.append(userInput)
            print("Item added. Basket Total:","£",round(total,3))
        except KeyError:
            print("Please enter a valid item.")

    ## This prints the items in their basket
    print("\n--- Your Shopping List ---")
    for i in shopping_list:
        print(i.title())

    ## This prints the total of their basket
    print("Total: £"+str(total))
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your particular logic (which is up to you to decide whether or not solves your problem), you are probably using the `elif` operator incorrectly:

if the user entered `milk` then, increase the total by 1.55

```
    if userInput.lower() == "milk":
        total += 1.55
```

contextually, if the user entered `bread` then, increase the total by 1.82

```
    if userInput.lower() == "bread":
        total += 1.82
```

contextually, if the user entered `butter` then, increase the total by 1.29

```
    if userInput.lower() == "butter":
        total += 1.29
```

and so on... until the last one:
contextually, if the user entered `coffee` then, increase the total by 3.05

```
    if userInput.lower() == "coffee":
        total += 3.05
```

contextually, if the user didn't enter `coffee` **and** what the user entered is not contained in the list `items` write `Please enter a valid item.`

```
    elif userInput not in items:
        print("Please enter a valid item.")
```

The last check is redundant as you already checked against them.
As the user enters a string, which you check against a collection of non-overlapping values (milk, bread, etc...), you should turn all your `if` into `elif` as follows:

```
    if userInput.lower() == "milk":
        total += 1.55
    elif userInput.lower() == "bread":
        total += 1.82
    elif userInput.lower() == "butter":
        total += 1.29
    elif userInput.lower() == "salt":
        total += 1.20
    elif userInput.lower() == "pepper":
        total += 1.20
    elif userInput.lower() == "ham":
        total += 1.99
    elif userInput.lower() == "steak":
        total += 3.99
    elif userInput.lower() == "banana bunch":
        total += 2.25
    elif userInput.lower() == "apple tray":
        total += 1.52
    elif userInput.lower() == "grapes":
        total += 1.41
    elif userInput.lower() == "winegums":
        total += 0.85
    elif userInput.lower() == "black jacks":
        total += 0.85
    elif userInput.lower() == "sugar":
        total += 2.95
    elif userInput.lower() == "honey":
        total += 0.85
    elif userInput.lower() == "tea":
        total += 2.85
    elif userInput.lower() == "coffee":
        total += 3.05
    else
        print("Please enter a valid item.")
```

Which essentialy is a `switch` statement.

**My personal note**: as you aldready have a list of elements, you could just create a dictionary of *product names to coefficients*, therefore, the whole stuff would be reduced to a find in a dictionary, which, in my opinion, is more maintanable than hardcoding the values within the method.